# Customized Hook with Observer not Rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

React published a nice [custom hook example](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) (`useFriendStatus`) where the hook subscribes to an API to update the online status.
I tried to simulate this example. My hook looks like the following:

```
export default function useStore(id) {
  const [data, setStatus] = useState(DataLayer.getData());



  useEffect(() => {

    function handleStatusChange() {
      console.log("udpate ...." + id);
      console.log(DataLayer.getData());
      setStatus(DataLayer.getData());
    }

    DataLayer.register({"id":id, "callback":handleStatusChange});
    setStatus(DataLayer.getData());
    return () => {
      DataLayer.unregister(id, handleStatusChange);
    };
  });


  return data;
}
```

The DataLayer implements a setInterval method which permanently notifies the hook and changes the data for testing purposes. Hence, I always get on my console the update.... message as well as the current object. This works fine!

My component looks like the following, **but it does not re-render**:

```
function MyComponent (props) {
  const config = useStore(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1));


  return (
    <div >
      <pre>
        <code> {JSON.stringify(config, null, 3)} </code>
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Why is my component,which uses the custom hook not updating?

Comment: you are not getting console.log(config)???

Comment: Could you give me a more detailed feedback: what do you mean with console.log(config)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customHook works fine! The problem seems to be `setState` with an object. You have to create **a copy** of it every time when you want to update the state, e.g. with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obejct))`

Simpliy passing a modified object to `setState` is NOT enough.